# How to fix error: The schemas property will be ignored because your document does not declare any matching target namespaces

Tags: android, xml, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xsd

Using Visual Studio 2015 - Xamarin Android

When I hover over the LinearLayout element of one of my axml files, I get this warning

> "The schemas property will be ignored because your document does not
>   declare any matching target namespaces."

When I right click on the xml file and choose properties it shows 2 schemas selected.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">...
```

The 2 schemas are
`C:\Source\MobileApp\test\MyApp\obj\Debug\Schemas\21\android-layout-xml.xsd` `C:\Source\MobileApp\test\MyApp\obj\Debug\Schemas\21\schemas.android.com.apk.res.android.xsd`

I changed my app name above, for this post but kept the rest intact.
I don't get what it's asking for.

I created a new app and I'm not getting that error.
The only difference I can see is the new app references folder \23\ and not \21.
I tried removing the 21 folder and replacing it with the one from my test app and it just recreates it.

It almost feels like intellisense for Xamarin was never added.
Thanks ahead of time for any and all help.

Comment: Try to update all Nuget packages for solution and check References. Are libraries the same in both solutions including version?